# Java ImageIO: How can I read a BufferedImage from file, so that it uses DataBufferFloat?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, javax.imageio

I need to read a `BufferedImage` from file, which doesn't use `DataBufferInt` (as normally), but `DataBufferFloat`.

**Please note:** I don't just need some standalone `DataBufferFloat`, but really a `BufferedImage` with underlying `DataBufferFloat`.

The API around these things is very complex, I just can't find how to do this.

Please help.

---

**EDIT**
Found out what is **not** working:

```
DataBufferDouble dbd = new DataBufferDouble(destWidth * destHeight * 4);

// Exception here:
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported data type 5
WritableRaster wr = WritableRaster.createPackedRaster(
    dbd, destWidth, destHeight, 32, new Point(0, 0));

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(ColorModel.getRGBdefault(),
    wr, false, (Hashtable<?, ?>) null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createPackedRaster` is not appropriate for this.  It creates a `Raster` with a `SinglePixelPackedSampleModel`, which stores r/g/b/a values in bit fields within an `int`, so its `transferType` can only be an integral type.

You probably want a generic raster with a `PixelInterleavedSampleModel` e.g.

```
DataBufferDouble dbd = new DataBufferDouble(destWidth * destHeight * 4);

SampleModel sm = new PixelInterleavedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE, destWidth, destHeight, 4, destWidth * 4, new int[] {2, 1, 0, 3});

WritableRaster wr = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sm, dbd, null);

ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_LINEAR_RGB), true, true, ColorModel.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT);

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(cm, wr, true, new Hashtable<Object, Object>());
```